# SQL Query Returns empty Recordset

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

I'm trying to learn how to connect to a SQL Server DB from Excel DB. I've tried to reduce the code to dead simple to begin with.  I've looked at several answers to related questions, however, I cannot figure out why this doesn't work. It executes all the way through. (The code shown here is somewhat anonymized.)

The query finds the database, because if the table name is invalid it throws an error.  However it always returns record count = -1.  I can eyeball the table in MSSMS and it has data.  Same result for other tables in the DB.

```
Public Sub ADOtest1()

Dim Conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strConnString As String

strConnString = "Provider='SQLOLEDB'" & ";" & _
               "Data Source='XXX-XPS\SQLEXPRESS'" & ";" & _
               "Initial Catalog='XXXXX'" & ";" & _
               "Integrated Security='SSPI'"

Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection
Conn.Open strConnString

' the query finds the DB, because if the table name is incorrect, it throws an error
strSQLString = "SELECT * from t300_XXXX"

Set rs = Conn.Execute(strSQLString)
wrkRecordCount = rs.RecordCount

'--- just some test breakpoints
If wrkRecordCount = -1 Then
    a = ""  '--- code keeps arriving here
Else
    a = ""
End If

rs.Close
Conn.Close

End Sub
```

Answer from Srinika below worked:

```
Set rs = Conn.Execute(strSQLString)
rs.Close
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.Open
```

Comment: Check whether the `Initial Catalog` is the same as the table that you are looking. Also check whether the schema is `dbo`, and to check further put the table name as `dbo.t300_XXXX`.

Comment: Keep in mind that `RecordCount` is not accurate until you move the pointer to the last record in the recordset. Check `EOF` and `BOF` instead.

Comment: Also try adding `rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient` before getting the rec count

Comment: rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient worked;  needed to close rs before and open afterwards; see note in original post. Thanks!  FYI: dbo did not make a difference. Was not sure how to use EOF/BOF.

Comment: `"Data Source='XXX-XPS\SQLEXPRESS'" & ";" & _`  to `"Data Source=XXX-XPS\SQLEXPRESS" & ";" & _`

Answer (score 0):

I'll post two examples, so please refer.

1. First Example

---

```
Sub ExampleSQL()

   Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
   Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
   Dim strSQL As String

   Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

   'Set the provider property to the OLE DB Provider for ODBC.
   'cnn.Provider = "MSDASQL"
   'cnn.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
   'cnn.Provider = "MSOLAP"
   'cnn.Provider = "SQLOLEDB.1"
   ' Open a connection using an ODBC DSN.
   cnn.ConnectionString = "driver={SQL Server};" & _
      "server=severname;uid=sa;pwd=password;database=test"

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [your Table] "

    rs.Open strSQL, cnn.ConnectionString, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

    cnn.Open
    If cnn.State = adStateOpen Then
    Else
       MsgBox "Sever is not connected!! "
       Exit Sub
    End If

    If Not rs.EOF Then
         With Ws
            .Range("a4").CurrentRegion.ClearContents
            For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
               .Cells(4, i + 1).Value = rs.Fields(i).Name
            Next
            .Range("a5").CopyFromRecordset rs
            .Columns.AutoFit
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "No Data!!", vbCritical
    End If
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

    cnn.Close
    Set cnn = Nothing
End Sub
```

2. Second Example

---

```
Sub getDataFromServer()
    Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

    Dim i As Integer

    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;" _
             & "Server=(local);" _
             & "Database=TEST;" _
             & "Integrated Security=SSPI;" _
             & "DataTypeCompatibility=80;"

    con.Open

    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = con
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [your Table]"
    Set rs = cmd.Execute
    Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs

    con.Close
    Set con = Nothing

End Sub
```